# Wrong results in group_by by month with javascript date objects in node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, group-by

I have a problem using `javascript` date objects in a `node` app and running queries through `postgresql`.

I have following data in a csv file (first column: date, second column: amount)

```
08/08/2022;620,00
01/08/2022;-73,41
01/08/2022;600,00
01/08/2022;-341,36
```

Since date format is not standard, I convert it manually to a date object:

```
 new Date(year, month, day);
```

I store it to a `postgresql` database through the `prisma` client.

The `date` field is following type in `schema.prisma`

```
model Transaction {
  id                Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  amount            Float   
  date              DateTime @db.Date
```

which corresponds to this migration:

```
ALTER TABLE "Transaction" ALTER COLUMN "date" SET DATA TYPE DATE;
```

Once data is stored, it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 9205,
        "date": "2022-08-07T22:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 9206,
        "amount": -73.41,
        "date": "2022-07-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 9207,
        "amount": 600,
        "date": "2022-07-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 9208,
        "amount": -341.36,
        "date": "2022-07-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    }
]
```

Dates look good, I double-checked running `.getMonth`, creating the date again in the browser etc.

I try to run a raw query with `prisma`:

```
const expensesByMonths: any[] = await this.prisma.$queryRaw`
  SELECT 
    date_trunc('month', date) as date_month,
    sum(amount)
  FROM "public"."Transaction"
  GROUP BY
    date_month
`;
```

Unfortunately, the results are wrong:

```
{
    "expensesByMonths": [
        {
            "date_month": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "sum": -414.77
        }
    ],
    "incomesByMonths": [
        {
            "date_month": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "sum": 600
        },
        {
            "date_month": "2022-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "sum": 620
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand why `group_by` from `postgresql` is not understanding the `javascript` date objects, since they are strings at the end.

I guess I can't store in postgresql things like 2022-07-31T22:00:00.000Z, I see everywhere dates like '2022-11-23', not sure if it's stored as strings or dates

Comment: 1) `DateTime` is not a Postgres data type. 2) Postgres data types that cover what you want are `timestamp`, `timestamptz` or `date`. Looks like you are using one of the `timestamp` variants. If you only want to use dates then use `date`.

Comment: 1. What type is your date_month column in postgres? 
2. What are your expected results?

Comment: For storing dates with times also timezone, you should use Postgres `timestampz`, and having it in Prisma, you should use `DateTime` instead of Date. 

Also, you can use the toISOString() built-in function to convert js date to ISO string.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I am not storing DateTime, but Date. In prisma there's no Date object,  I had to use DateTime @db.Date, which apparently creates the Date type in postgresql. I updated my question with this info, and add the corresponding migration.

Comment: so I guess the question is, what to pass to prisma.transaction.create(), since date should be '2022-8-23' for postgresql, but it can't be a string for prisma. Not sure what to do